# Can we pass Rcpp::List or a vector of vectors to RcppParallel function?

Tags: rcppparallel

I have an R list which I convert to vector of vectors in Rcpp. Now I want to use RcppParallel to use multiple cores. Can I pass such a list or vector of vectors to RcppParallel similar to IntegerMatrix or IntegerVectors?

Comment: There is no thread safe wrapper for List, cf https://stackoverflow.com/a/38670133/8416610

Comment: @RalfStubner Thanks!