# Is Rcpp vector thread safe to use with OpenMP?

Tags: c++, r, multithreading, rcpp

I'm using Rcpp with OpenMP for parallel computation in C++. I read [Is accessing/setting elements in a Rcpp::List thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38669655/is-accessing-setting-elements-in-a-rcpplist-thread-safe) and it seems that using Rcpp inside a threaded code block is dangerous. But it is quite common to read or write on Rcpp NumericVectors in a for loop such as https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/hierarchical-risk-parity/.

Below is what I wrote. The task is straightforward. I first declare a `NumericVector` with a large size `n` outside a (parallel) for loop. I do some calculation and fill each element of the `NumericVector` using index `i`. Once done, I compute a desired quantile of it.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <omp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double foo(const int n, const int nthreads) {

  Rcpp::NumericVector out(n);
  #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(nthreads)
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    out[i] = doSomething();
  }

  Rcpp::Environment stats("package:stats");
  Rcpp::Function quantile = stats["quantile"];
  return Rcpp::as<double>(quantile(out, Rcpp::Named("probs") = 0.95));
}
```

I have two questions.

1. Is there any reason to use other containers (e.g. `std::vector<double>`) instead of `NumericVector` for thread safety? I tested the above code with `std::vector<double>` and got identical result. I heard that conversion between the two involves deep copy. If I use `std::vector<double>`, then does deep copying occur when `quntile()` is called?
2. If using `NumericVector` is safe, would it be better to just return `NumericVector` and apply `quntile()` in R in terms of performance?

Comment: It has been explained multiple times over. One good and concise discussion in the examples for package `RcppParallel` which tells you clearly why you _cannot_ use Rcpp's own `NumericVector` or `NumericMatrix` (and, hence, `List`) but rather its `RVector` and `RMatrix` as they keep data away from the (not thread-safe) R compute core.

Comment: Thanks @DirkEddelbuettel. I changed my code to use `std::vector`.